# Xhline too long in longtable

Tags: longtable, makecell

I am tyring to make a table with `longtable`. At regular intervals, I replace the standard `\hline` with `makecell`'s `\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}`. This mostly occurs below a `\multicolumn` cell.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Big header} \\
    \Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
    Some stuff & More stuff & Stuff without lipsums \\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, just as in my actual document, the `\Xhline` will wrap to the width of the *page*, not the width of the table. This leads to this kind of unconveniently ugly result:

[image: Xhline too large]

Questions:

- What can be cause of this weird result?
- How can I avoid it (i.e. the `\Xhline` stops at the table border)?

Comment: longtables are always full width so that is the expected result from a standard `\hline` (longtable locally gives `\hline` a completey different definition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A work-around consists in using `Xcline`instead.

Another  solution uses the  `boldline`package, from the `shipunov` bundle: its `\hlineB` command takes  longtable into account. Note that the argument for this command is just a number (the `multiple` of `\arrayrulewidth`), not a length as `\Xhline`. In addition, `boldline` has a simple syntax for thicker vertical lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell, boldline}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Big header} \\
    \Xcline{1-3}{2\arrayrulewidth}
    Some stuff & More stuff & Stuff without lipsums \\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Big header} \\
    \hlineB{2}
    Some stuff & More stuff & Stuff without lipsa \\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Made it work with `boldline`. +1 for correcting the plural of "lipsum"  '^^

Comment: 'Twas just for fun: anyway, it's not really a Latin word ;o)